# Woher kommt das Wort Spinozerus?

Tags: etymology

Ich kenne den Spinozerus als eine Person, die ungewöhnliche Ideen verfolgt.

Woher kommt dieses Wort?

Comment: _"woher kommt dieses Wort"_ - Meinst Du damit, _"aus welcher geographischen Gegend / soziologischen Gruppe /o.ä. kommt dieses Wort"_ oder _"wie ist dieses Wort entstanden"_?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: gibt sicher einige Reime; Vgl. z.B. *Uterus*, " Proto-Indo-European \*úderos (“abdomen, stomach”), from \*úd (“out, outward”) +‎ \*-eros (contrastive suffix)." (comparativ \*-eros, superlativ \*-est), "sich was *aus*-spinnen" (wie ich gerade);

Comment: google findet 5 (fünf) Ergebnisse für Spinotarus, "Spinotarus caboverdus", ein biologische Taxon (scheinbar ein Tausenfüsler). ... Welches bei näherer Betrachtung nur ein Typo für *Spinotar**s**us* ist.

Comment: @vectory  Das ist interessant, weil es zur Vermutung leitet, dass auch engl. *udder* (das Euter) von *úderos* kommt. Aber mit dem *Spinozerus* sehe ich jetzt keine rechte Verbindung...

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann es ging mir primär um die Endung.

Comment: Ich wundere mich ob der Spinozerus mit dem holländischen Philosophen Baruch Spinoza zusammen hängt?

Answer (score 5):

Ich habe Spinozerus noch nie gehört, aber laut dem
[Digitalen Wörterbuch der Kasseler Mundart](http://www.dwkm.de/woerterbucheintrag/Spinozerus.html?lang=ks&currency=Spinozerus) bedeutet es:

> Spinozerus: einer, der spinnesiert (s.d.), ein schlauer, verschlagener Bursch

[spinnesieren](http://www.dwkm.de/woerterbucheintrag/spinnesieren.html) wird wiederum wird auf

> seltener für das Hochdeutsche spintisieren (grübeln)

zurückgeführt,

wozu der [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/spintisieren) sagt:

> spintisieren
>
> Bedeutungsübersicht: eigenartigen, wunderlichen, abwegigen Gedanken nachgehen
>
> Beispiel: anfangen [über etwas] zu spintisieren
>
> **Herkunft ungeklärt, wahrscheinlich romanisierende Weiterbildung zu
> deutsch spinnen (3a)**

---

Ein rein subjektiver Kommentar bezüglich der Ähnlichkeit von Spinozerus mit **Rhinozeros** (Nilpferd) oder **Baruch Spinoza** (holländischer Philosoph): Ich denke das ist reiner Zufall. Google vermutet übrigens einen Schreibfehler bei der Suche nach Spinozerus und verweist wenig hilfreich auf die Suchergebnisse zum  **Spinosaurus**, einer Dinosaurier Art.

Comment: Menno, du warst eine Zehntelsekunde schneller...

Comment: @IQV, aber du hast eine andere Quelle

Comment: Dafür sind beide Antworten trotz unterschiedlicher Quellen fast wortgleich :-) ...

Comment: @iqv Und ich war am langsamsten und habe trotzdem nicht gesehen, dass es schon Antworten gab.

Answer (score 4):

Ich habe dieses Wort noch nie vorher gehört, aber eine Suchmaschine führt zu einem [Wörterbuch der niederhessischen Mundart](http://www.kasselwiki.de/index.php?title=W%C3%B6rterbuch_der_niederhessischen_Mundart,_S), wo es aufgeführt ist. Somit scheint es aus Niederhessen, aus der Gegend um Kassel zu kommen.

In dem Wörterbuch wird als Bedeutung aufgeführt

> Spinozerus: jem., der spinnesiert; ein schlauer, verschlagener Bursche

wobei wiederum laut dem Wörterbuch

> spinnesieren: meist "spionieren, auskundschaften", seltener für hd. spintisieren "grübeln"

bedeutet. Das ist allerdings das einzige Vorkommen dieses Wortes, das ich gefunden habe, insofern weiß ich nicht, ob diese eine Website zutreffend ist.

Answer (score 3):

- Der Duden kennt das Wort *Spinozerus* nicht,
- das Digitale Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache kennt es nicht (und das bedeutet, es ist in einer ganzen Reihe relevanter Wörterbücher – Grimm, Pfeifer, Wörterbuch der deutschen Gegenwartsprache etc. – und großer Textkorpora nicht aufgeführt) und
- – als letzte große Instanz ;-) – ich kenne es auch nicht.

Wenn es dieses Wort gibt, ist es vermutlich mundartlich.
Es ist auch tatsächlich aufgeführt im [Wörterbuch der Kasseler Mundart](http://www.dwkm.de/woerterbucheintrag/Spinozerus.html) als

> einer, der spinnesiert (s.d.), ein schlauer, verschlagener Bursch

Das Verb *spinnesieren* findet sich in den üblichen Quellen ebensowenig wie *Spinozerus*, aber im [selben Wörterbuch](http://www.dwkm.de/woerterbucheintrag/spinnesieren.html) ist es aufgeführt als

> 1. seltener für das Hochdeutsche spintisieren (grübeln)
> 2. kasselisch meist für: spionisieren und in diesem Falle = feschgahlen (s.d.; vgl. auch: Brenne[)]

Sofern das stimmt, wären zwei Etymologien denkbar:

Für *spintisieren* kommt laut [Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GS35419#XGS35419) eine Herkunft aus der italienischen Kaufmannssprache infrage (mehr Infos dort).
Laut [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/spintisieren) ist die

> Herkunft ungeklärt, wahrscheinlich romanisierende Weiterbildung zu deutsch spinnen (3a)

Die andere Option wäre *Spion*.
Das ist laut [Pfeifer](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Spion) vermutlich ebenfalls aus dem Italienischen ins Deutsche gewandert.

Comment: Warum erwähnt niemand das **Rhinozeros**, das doch hier sicherlich Pate gestanden haben wird?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Ich hatte spontan an den Philosophen _Spinoza_ gedacht.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich  Das mag ja für den Wortanfang (Spinoz...) durchaus sein. Jedoch das ...erus oder ...zerus ist so selten, auch im Bildungssprachendeutsch, dass als Quelle eigentlich nur das Nashorn in Frage kommt. Finde ich. Ansonsten gibts ja nur noch... Lazarus... ?

Comment: Kann es nicht sein, dass das ...erus eine Wortbildung aus dem süddeutschen Raum ist? Ich bin leider schon eine Ewigkeit in Nordamerika zu Hause und nicht mehr ganz 100% in der deutschen Sprache

Comment: @margot  Ich bin in Süddeutschland aufgwachsen und habe das noch nie gehört. Also jedenfall im südlichen Süddeutschland. (Alles nördlich der Schwäbischen Alb ist für uns praktisch Norddeutschland. Da fährt man nie hin.)

Comment: @margot, auch aus der der Region um Stuttgart kenne ich Spinozerus nicht.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm...

Ich fand das hier:

> Ich kenne einen
>   kleinen Knaben, dem der Mund seines Vaters oft ein Hosiannah
>   den Philosophen und Dichtern singt, und dem daher Männer
>   wie Kant, Leibnitz, Spinoza nicht völlig unbekannt sind. Ein
>   Spaziergang in den zoologischen Garten legte neulich für seine
>   künftigen naturwissenschaftlichen Studien die Basis: man errät,
>   dass er bald darauf, nach seinem Liebling unter den Philosophen
>   gefragt, mit ernsthafter Miene zur Antwort gab: Spinozeros

Aus: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1d/Michaelis_Studien_zur_romanischen_Wortsch%C3%B6pfung.pdf

Also in diesem Text ist es eine Kontraktion von *Spinoza* und *Rhinozeros*.

Ich weiß aber nicht, ob so eine Kontraktion wirklich der Usprung des Wortes *Spinozerus* ist.